# Masking URL in the addressbar

Tags: asp.net

I am working on asp.net application where there are one master page and several content (aspx) page. In master page menu is populating from database and entire application is working fine.

Now I don't want to show the actual URL in the address bar when I am clicking the menu. In the above scenario content page link is showing in the URL (address bar).

Is there any way where my content page will show/load in the Content Placeholder without changing the URL in the address bar.

Comment: Why don't you want to show it? If it is for security reasons then masking won't really help at all...

Comment: Because in the url i am passing some parameter which I don't want show the user. Is there any way to show it in iframe when clicking the master page menu

Comment: even in an iframe it would be the same, what you need is to load the content via a click event. and then render the response. Thats the only way you can be sure not to expose parameters